# Trying to get certain values with mysql php?

Tags: php, mysql

Look at my table, I am trying to get the fruit from USA with ups shipping and also any fruit that doesn't include USA. Look at my table, apple include USA and ups, berry doesn't include USA. So I want to get apple and berry. The below query is the best I got, but it fail, it doesn't echo berry which doesn't include usa.

```
SELECT fruit FROM table fruit WHERE shipping = 'ups' AND country ='USA' GROUP BY fruit


table fruit        
fruit  country    shipping  
apple   USA        ups
apple   China      ups
apple    UK        ups
banana    USA      fedez
banana   Russia    fedez
banana   Italy     fedez
berry    Italy     fedez
berry    China     fedez
berry    French    fedez
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT fruit FROM fruit WHERE (country = "USA" AND shipping = "ups") OR fruit NOT IN (SELECT fruit FROM fruit WHERE country = "USA") GROUP BY fruit
```

```
SELECT fruit
FROM fruit
WHERE
    (country = "USA" AND shipping = "ups")
    OR
    fruit NOT IN (
        SELECT fruit FROM fruit WHERE country = "USA"
    )
GROUP BY fruit
```

So if I'm right, the first statement will return you `apple`. The second one has a nested query which will return `apple` and `banana` because both have country USA , and the statement will find the fruit which is not in this group , so it is `berry`. So in the end it will only return `apple` and `berry`

If it echoes everything I will try it on my computer.

Comment: This is working, but it returns `[apple, berry, berry, berry]` and I suppose the OP just wants `[apple, berry]`. You can move the `GROUP BY` to the end of the main SELECT.

Comment: @akinuri aah yes I didn't see that coming. Editing the answer now.

Comment: Also do you mind if I edit the query to make it more readable? I think it deserves some highlight :)

Comment: @akinuri it is the only answer in this post written in lowercase :( go ahead :)

Answer (score 0):

try this one

`SELECT fruit FROM fruit WHERE (shipping = 'ups' AND country = 'USA') OR country NOT IN('USA');`

Comment: Thanks for response. It echo everything. I am using GROUP BY, but it still echo everything. I think the reason is that the table contain three rows of banana. When you say country not in ('usa'), the other two rows has no USA but still banana, that is why it echo every fruit. how to solve this?

Comment: do you want it should't display the rows that contain `banana` ?

Comment: @FahadKazmi banana includes USA. So it shouldn't be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

SELECT fruit FROM fruit WHERE (shipping = 'ups' AND country = 'USA') OR country ! = 'USA' GROUP BY fruit;

Comment: It echo every fruit.

Answer (score 0):

You can write this

```
SELECT fruit FROM fruit WHERE (shipping = 'ups' AND country = 'USA') OR fruit NOT IN (SELECT fruit FROM fruit WHERE country = 'USA' GROUP BY fruit);
```

Comment: Thanks for response. It echo everything. I am using GROUP BY, but it still echo everything. I think the reason is that the table contain three rows of banana. When you say country not in ('usa'), the other two rows has no USA but still banana, that is why it echo every fruit. how to solve this?

Comment: See your db. If banana is not in USA it is in not USA. So that it shows all. What do you want to do??

Comment: you and I now almost have the same answer but yours is still wrong after update because after `OR` you are comparing `country` but your nested query returns `fruit`so it will still echo every fruit.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. Yeah you are right. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT f.fruit 
FROM TableFruit AS f 
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableFruit AS usa ON f.fruit=usa.fruit and usa.country='USA'
WHERE f.shipping = 'ups' AND f.country ='USA' 
   OR usa.country IS NULL
```

Explanation: An OUTER JOIN returns nulls for all columns in the joined table if there is no row that satisfies the join condition. In this case, it's looking for a row `b` that has the same fruit as `f` and the country of USA. Therefore if there is no row with country USA, country will be null.